# How to remove the unwanted jagged aliasing in Arial/Times Font for "writing-mode: vertical-rl & transform: rotate(180deg)"?

Tags: css, layout, fonts, vertical-alignment, css-transforms

Given some vertical text as part of a sideways navigation using simply and only:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

However, on both Chrome & Firefox, on both of my standard fontfaces used ***Arial*** & ***Times News Roman*** text becomes jagged aliased and has a wrong letterspacing.

I have discovered that by adding `0.1` to the degrees this "solves" the aliasing and renders the font beautifully and faithfully without any jagged aliasing:

```
transform: rotate(180.1deg);
```

However, this adds a slanted tilt and an extra pixel to the right of the menu items, long story short: it is not a(n elegant) solution to my problem and creates new problems.

Is there another (more elegant) way to get rid of the jagged aliasing introduced by the combination of vertical-rl and rotate(180deg)?

---

Arial/Times, 180degrees, straight but jagged and aliased.
Notice also how the letter spacing looks incorrect!
[image: Arial]  [image: Times]

---

Arial/Times, 180.1degrees, no jagged aliasing and a correct spacing between letters.
But everything is slanted and tilted which is unwanted:
[image: Arial]  [image: Times]

---

### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/8Lrv5epw/

Comment: Try adding  *letter-spacing* CSS property and play with it.

Comment: I reproduced the same example as in your image and i had smooth fonts in both Firefox and Chrome. [screenshot](https://ibb.co/SRHyymc) Can you add a snippet with your code?

Comment: I'm on Win11 and ClearType turned ON, Nvidia RTX 3060Ti, driver 512.59, Firefox v101.0 Chrome 102.0.5005.63. I'm not no sure about the impact, since Win10 and Win11 aren't too different. It's better to compare your snippet in my local pc, if it looks good then might be something is wrong on your side.

Comment: @Anton I see, indeed should not be that different from my Chrome 102 W10 64bit Pro ClearType turned ON. Updated my question with a working demo: jsfiddle.net/8Lrv5epw

Comment: I don't see a problem with fonts on my PC. [link](https://ibb.co/LYVrJM7). Try this second step [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en) when i unchecked and restarted Chrome i got the same result like you have on your PC. [link](https://ibb.co/b7fmJG9)

Comment: My bad, I have 120% zoom in both Firefox and Chrome. Now i see a problem at zoom 100%.

Comment: Fwiw this only happens to me when I have monitors with two different resolutions. I have a 4k and a 1440 and it only shows as messed up on the 1440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution to solve this problem. You need a **box-sizing** property with a value  of **border-box**.

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

nav {
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-size: 1.2em; /* was 1em */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li a {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0.8); /* scale down */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  height: auto;
  font-family: "Arial";
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

nav li {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0em;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

nav li:first-of-type {
  border-top: none
}

nav li a {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* transform: rotate(180.1deg); */
}

nav li.selected,
nav li.selected a {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Bureau</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Initiatief</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dienst</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ontwerp</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Concept</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Oeuvre</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks but helas No effect at all on a W10 Chrome. With and without that part in your snippet makes not even a subpixel difference on my PC. Same in Firefox: no difference on a W10! There must be something else!

Comment: I suppose **Arial** doesn't like `writing-mode: vertical-rl;`. As test, i took **Roboto** instead of  **Arial** and the menu text became smooth. So, i tried to do some trick. i set font a little bit bigger and then scale it down using transformation. Try this solution.

Comment: Awesome find! I will give it a trythis evening. I think we have reached the end of all the possibilities of this quirck and quest together!